# Angular - NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3094/api/Controller/Action/

Tags: angularjs, api, http-post, httprequest

I'm going to post my string to api, but every time I have got such error. However,by fiddler it's working fine

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3094/api/Controller/Action/
```

It's my js code

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('http://localhost:3094/api/Country/GetSelectionCount/' ,
        {id:selection})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
```

And server code

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [ActionName("GetSelectionCount")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSelectionCount(string id)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            return NotFound();

        var result= (from m in db.Products
                     where m.ProductName.Contains(id)
                     select m).Count();

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: You are doing a post but the server code says only get?

Comment: Sorry,don't mention these code:) it's just simple code for testing, that's why I called like that, the main point is that, this GetSelectionCount function get an parameter from UI and returns some data to client side. And if I change [AcceptVerbs("GET")]  to [AcceptVerbs("POST")] or [HttpPost] attribute,anyway it doesn't work (((

Comment: I have another post which is working, but in this post it's is getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 is normal in this situation. you are posting an object from angular which has an id property but on the server side you are expecting a string property. so .net cant match action.

you either need to change your server side action parameter or angular posted data

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string id {get;set;}
}
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[ActionName("GetSelectionCount")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSelectionCount([FromBody] MyModel model)
{
    if (model == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.id))
        return NotFound();

    var result= (from m in db.Products
                 where m.ProductName.Contains(model.id)
                 select m).Count();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: I used a model on server side for parameter but I got the same error. Then I used  $http.post('http://localhost:3094/api/Country/GetSelectionCount/' ,
        selection)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })

Comment: can you post your model on asp.net

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApi.Demo.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class JustModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: you need to rename Text to id

Comment: i added necessary code to my answer, to catch what you posted from angular

Comment: yes, I used like that  public IHttpActionResult GetSelectionCount(JustModel text)    but it didn't work

Comment: Oh,after writing [HttpPost] attribute it's working fine, thank you very much )))

Answer (score 0):

I think 404 has more to do with routing engine not able to find the relevant action method on controller. You can confirm it by using `Route` attribute like

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[ActionName("GetSelectionCount")]
[Route("api/country/GetSelectionCount/")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSelectionCount(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        return NotFound();

    var result= (from m in db.Products
                 where m.ProductName.Contains(id)
                 select m).Count();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: do u still get 404 message or something else?